# Hierarchy of arithmetic operations in C.

Tags: c, hierarchy

When I type my code like given below :

```
int a=10,b,c,d,e;
c= a++;
d = ++a;
e = ++a;
printf("value of c=%d, d =%d, e=%d",c,d,e);
```

it gives me an output like `c =10` , `d= 12`, `e=13` 
and when we add these values,i.e `10+12+13` becomes  `35`,
but when I code it like :

```
b = a++ + ++a + ++a;
printf("value of b=%d" ,b);
```

it gives me output `36`.

Can somebody describe what's the process behind this code and why the output of codes are different?
Thank you!

Comment: The second snippet isn't guaranteed to always result in 36.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/could-anyone-explain-these-undefined-behaviors-i-i-i-i-i-etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delicious [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), the order of evaluation of the operands of `+` (and many others) is left to the implementation. So it's not even always `36` for the second case.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a=10,b,c,d,e;
c= a++;
d = ++a;
e = ++a;
printf("value of c=%d, d =%d, e=%d",c,d,e);
```

In statement `c = a++` , value of `a` is used first(which is `10`) and then incremented to`11`.
 Statement `d = ++a` first increment `a` (which is `12` now) and then use its value to print in `printf()` statement.
 Same for `e = ++a`.

Your second snippet

```
b = a++ + ++a + ++a;
printf("value of b=%d" ,b);
```

results in Undefined Behavior(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: thanks for clarify all the things .....your answer is correct too.

Comment: I am glad that it helped you. See FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score -1):

Difference between them is second expression has not ended with a++ and yet to add some other values thats why a++ is 11, not 10